# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory,

Tags: node.js, express

When I'm trying to upload images and save in public/upload_files folder through postman it shows this error

node -v  v10.15.3

npm -v   6.9.0

> "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory"

This is my code

```
const express = require('express'); 

const router = express.Router();    
const multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({    
  destination: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null,'./public/uploaded_files');    
  },    
  filename: function(req, file, cb) {       
    cb(null,new Date().toISOString() + file.originalname);    
  } 
});

const upload = multer({storage:storage});    

router.post('/', upload.single('file'), (req,res,next) => {    
  console.log(req.file);
});

module.exports = router;
```

I'm just trying to save the images in the following folder public/upload_files

Comment: not working I tried.

Comment: the folders you wrote, do they exist ?

Comment: yes it exists. It gives me this error                                                                    
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\Event\public\uploaded_files\2019-04-20T20:34:21.195Z025.JPG'

Comment: `D:\Event\public\uploaded_files\`  is this path correct ?

Comment: yes it is full path D:\Event\public\uploaded_files

Comment: Maybe try without the full-stop `.` in your path like this `'\public\uploaded_files'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I made few changes to my code and it worked.

I added this line

```
cb(null,path.join(__dirname,'../upload'))
```

and this

```
cb(null,Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
```

code

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    
destination: function(req, file, cb)
    
{
        
cb(null,path.join(__dirname,'../upload'))
 
},
    
filename: function(req, file, cb)
    
{
        
cb(null,Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
    }
});
```

Comment: Didn't work for me so I used relative path

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname);
```

instead of

```
cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + file.originalname);
```

to prevent

```
"error": "ENOENT: no such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

It may due to a forbidden filename or OS action. Did you ran the program in different OS? For eg: Some OS does not allow filename with some special characters as produced by the new Date().toISOString() function.
Extra: I think this code is from the Node js course from Max.

Answer (score 0):

Works with me...

```
cb(null, './uploads/');
```

and...

```
cb(null, new Date().getTime() + file.originalname);
```

the final result is...

```
filename: '1656962448485IMG-20200414-WA0030.jpg',
path: 'uploads\\1656962448485IMG-20200414-WA0030.jpg',
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new Date().toISOString()
```

is not a properName for windows file system to save a file.
try using

```
Date.now()
```

or

```
new Date().getTime()
```

or anything which doesnt include invalid characters

Answer (score -1):

```
  const storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function(req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, './public/uploaded_files');
        },
        filename: function(req, file, cb) {
             // cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + file.originalname) // this is wrong
            cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname);
        }
    });
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.