# Nodejs express multer file upload + path contains double slashes

Tags: node.js, multer

I'm trying to upload an image to my directory using Postman. I am using Nodejs and multer as a middleware.

However, I get an ENOENT error:
[image: EnoEnt]

My question is as follows, why does my code give double \\, and what can I do to change double backslashes to forward slash in the pathname?

My code so far is:

```
const multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, '.test/');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + file.originalname);
  },
});
```

```
router.post('/', upload.single('productImage'), (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.file);
...
...
...
```

I have tried using the .replace() method without any success.

```
const multer = require('multer');

let destination = '.uploads/';

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, destination.replace('\\','/'));
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + file.originalname);
  },
});
```

I have also tried searching similar posts here on StackOverflow, e.g trying this posts answer [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55777362/error-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: `.test/` is not valid path. you should work with the `path` module and backticks ("`") to concatenate strings (paths)

Comment: You replace will only replace one instance, Try cb(null, destination.replace(/\\\\/g, '/')); to replace all instances.

Comment: Still ENOENT error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer after a bit of googling.

The problem was not the double \\, they are allowed, the problem was in the way the filename was saved. The filename was of a datestring, and was saved in the format: `2020-11-25T12:15something`, the problem is that Windows OS does not accept files with the character ":".

Solution would be to replace this line of code :

`cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + file.originalname);`

with

`cb(null, new Date().toISOString().replace(/:/g, '-') + file.originalname);`

[Original answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48418680/enoent-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `path.normalize('\\dsgsd\\sdgsdg')` method. You can find it in official NodeJS documentation https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_normalize_path

```js
const multer = require('multer');
const { normalize } = require('path')

let destination = '.uploads/';

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, normalize(destination));
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + file.originalname);
  },
});
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using macOS. If you use macOS, you must change the path as like Unix systems.

Comment: @haycon Did you try ```let destination = path.join(__dirname, '/uploads/');``` ??

Comment: Yes, that did not work. I found the answer however, read my other answer if you are curious about how it was done.